# Shrink the dataset by taking mean or median

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
Number     Apples
1            40
2            50
3            60
4            70
5            80
6            90
7            100
8            110
9            120
```

I want to shrink this dataset and create dataframe `df2` such that there are only 3 observations. Hence, I want to take the average of 1,2,3 and make that one row, then 4,5,6 and make that the second row, and finally, 7,8,9 and make that the 3rd row

The end result will be the following

```
Number     Apples
1            50
2            80
3            110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
n=3
s=df.groupby((df.Number-1)//n).Apples.mean()
Number
0     50
1     80
2    110
Name: Apples, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler approach and should run much faster than a groupby -

```
df.rolling(3).mean()[2::3]
```

```
    apples
2   50.0
5   80.0
8   110.0
```